# Finding a pair $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $\inf_{m,n\in \mathbb Z}\left|(m+\sqrt{3}n+a)(\sqrt{2}m+n+b) \right|>0$

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-approximation

I am trying the find a pair $(a,b)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $\inf_{m,n\in \mathbb Z}\left|(m+\sqrt{3}n+a)(\sqrt{2}m+n+b) \right|>0$

For $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$, I speculate that the infimum is nonzero. By [Dirichlet's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_approximation_theorem), we have $|\sqrt{2} m+n+\frac{1}{2}|\lesssim |\frac{1}{n}|$ for infinitely many $m,n$ and $\sqrt{2} m \asymp
 -n$. So $|m+\sqrt{3}n+a|\sim |n|$. But I don't see why
$$\inf_{m,n\in \mathbb Z}\left|(m+\sqrt{3}n+\frac{1}{2})(\sqrt{2}m+n+\frac{1}{2}) \right|>0$$

My question is about finding such a pair *explicitly*, but if you have a non-constructive proof showing that such pairs exist, please also let me know.

Comment: Where does the question come from? Just curiosity, or a course or a textbook?

Comment: @BartMichels It comes from my research. I will be happy to know if there are any courses or textbooks discussing such stuff. I can't find such in books on Diophantine approximations

Comment: @Derivative I believe you need to prove that there are infinitely many $m,n$ such that $(2+1)^2−3(2)^2=1$  and $0<+\sqrt{3}+1/2<1/48n^2$ hold simultaneously... it is very nontrivial to me